# How to write Functor instance

Tags: haskell, functor

I have a following type `data Summish a b = First a | Second b`.

How to write Functor instance for it?

I tried

```
instance Functor (Summish a) where
  fmap f (Second a) = Second (f a)
```

Comment: Didn't you get an error message?

Comment: @Al.G. No, because there is nothing illegal about this. You might get an inexhaustive pattern warning if you've opted into those.

Comment: So far so good. But `Summish` values don't all match the `Second` constructor. Finish the instance by defining the result for `First` values.

Comment: You could look at the instance for `Either a`, since `Summish` is identical to `Either` up to constructor names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to let the compiler do (*derive*) it for you:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Summish a b 
   = First a 
   | Second b
   deriving Functor
```

this only works if you have the [*derive functor* extension](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/derive-functor) enabled in **GHC** (for GHCi use `:set -XDeriveFunctor`).

So I guess you want/need to derive it manually.

As others stated you just need the case for `First` to make it *exhaustive*:

```hs
data Summish a b 
   = First a 
   | Second b

instance Functor (Summish a) where
   fmap f (First b) = First b
   fmap f (Second a) = Second (f a)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how you write a `Functor` instance.

The question is, is it a total, lawful instance?

If you add `deriving Show` to your data type, and you try to use this instance:

```
> fmap (+ 1) (Second 2)
Second 3

> fmap (+ 1) (First 2)
*** Exception: ...: Non-exhaustive patterns in function fmap
```

it seems that this `Functor` does not handle all possible values of `Summish a b`.